# Generate html code using lapply() with multiple arguments

Tags: r, htmltools

I am trying to generate several html paragraphs in a loop using `lapply()`. These paragraphs are in a `data.frame` and the `data.frame` have more columns with details for the paragraphs (class, id, etc).
I was able to produce the loop with only one argument, the problem is that I want more than one argument in the `lapply()` loop. Does anyone knows how to do this?

The `data.frame`:

```
df = data.frame(paragraph = c("paragraph1","paragraph2","paragraph3"),
                class= c("alert", "good", "alert"),
                id= c("id_1","id_2", "id_3"))
```

The objective is to have the following output:

```
<div>     
     <p class="alert" id="id_1">paragraph1</p> 
     <p class="good" id="id_2">paragraph2</p> 
     <p class="alert" id="id_3">paragraph3</p> 
</div>
```

The `lappy()` loop (for one argument only):

```
library(htmltools)
tags$div(lapply(df$paragraph, function(x){tags$p(class="", id="", x)}))
```

How can I do it so that the `class` and `id` gets filled in with the data in column `class` and `id` in `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` row-wise, and specify class, id, and content from your data frame as follows.

```
library(htmltools)

tags$div(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  tags$p(class = x[["class"]], id = x[["id"]], x[["paragraph"]])
}))
```

**Output**

```
<div>
  <p class="alert" id="id_1">paragraph1</p>
  <p class="good" id="id_2">paragraph2</p>
  <p class="alert" id="id_3">paragraph3</p>
</div>
```